# Laravel relationship between project and task

Tags: laravel

I have two models, Project and Tasks. I have defined them as follows:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function tasks() {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

}

class Task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'completed'];

    public function project() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
}
```

I want to print list of projects (1) and for each project I want to list tasks (2) and for each task I want to show detail of that **single** task (3).

To achieve (1) and (2) I have setup a projectsController (only showing relevant pieces):

```
class ProjectsController extends Controller
{

    public function index() {
        $projects = Project::all();
        return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
    }

    public function show(Project $project) {
        return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
    }    
}
```

and routes file:

```
Route::get('projects', array('as' => 'project-index', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@index'));
Route::get('project/{project}', array('as' => 'project-show', 'uses' => 'ProjectsController@show'));
```

In the view file for (1), I'm looping through with *@foreach( $projects as $project )* and for (2), I'm looping through with *@foreach( $project->tasks as $task )*. All works fine.

For (3) however, to show a single task I clicked, I have defined a TasksController:

```
class TasksController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Project $project, Task $task) {
        return view('tasks.show', compact('task'));
    }

}
```

and routes:

```
Route::get('project/{project}/task/{task}', array('as' => 'project-tasks-show', 'uses' => 'TasksController@show'));
```

I have issues finding how to best accomplish (3). In the view file, I can access the task detail as I'm passing the 'task' collection in the Taskscontroller.

I feel it is not efficient nor advisable:

- In the TasksController, I get an error when I only pass the Task
  $task, so I also must add the Project $project.
- As I have the $project collection anyway in the show function in the controller, is there a way I can pass the projects collection (instead of the task) to the view and then select only that task so I can use sth like $project->task in the view while having access to e.g $project->name as well.
- What is the proper way of handling this?

Comment: I guess you're binding models to route, right?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment but I don't think I'm using Route Model binding.

Comment: How do you set Project $project, Task $task variables in the show method?

Comment: It's in the router file with the statement  Route::get('project/{project}/task/{task}', array('as' => 'project-tasks-show', 'uses' => 'TasksController@show'));

Comment: It's no clear for me, because if you're using laravel you get a string or integer depends what you're receiving by the routes and not models, this is Why I was asking you by binding model in your route.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, if have foreign key of project_id in task model

```
  class TasksController extends Controller
  {
     public function show($project, $task) {
        $task = Task::where('project_id', $project)->find($task);
        return view('tasks.show', compact('task'));
     }
  }
```

and routes:

```
Route::get('project/{project}/task/{task}', array('as' => 'project-tasks-show', 'uses' => 'TasksController@show'));
```

And reply for it.